# Trying to Draw More Than 10 Marker In Google Map V3, Not Using GeoCoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get more than 10 markers drawn using google maps V3 but it stops at 10. I am not geo coding the markers, I already have the lat/long. Does anyone know why I would be having this issue? Below is the code I am using, it is nothing crazy.

```
var map = null;
var infowindow = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var venueLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($('#hdnVenueLat').val(), $('#hdnVenueLng').val());
    var options = {
        center: venueLatLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: venueLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: $("#hdnVenueName").val()
    });
    drawPoints();
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    $('.listing').click(function () {
        drawInfoWindow(markers[$(this).data('id')])
    })
})

function drawPoints() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng($('#hdnVenueLat').val(), $('#hdnVenueLng').val());
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    $('.listing').each(function (index) {
        var lat = $(this).data('lat').toString();
        var lng = $(this).data('lng').toString();
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var id = $(this).data('id').toString();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                id: id,
                position: latLng,
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/map-sprites.png', new google.maps.Size(26, 33), getImagePos(index)),
                //shadow: new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/map-sprites.png', new google.maps.Size(36, 24), new google.maps.Point(35, 345), new google.maps.Point(4, 15)),
                map: map,
                title: $(this).data('name')
            }
         );
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            drawInfoWindow(marker);
        });
        markers[id] = marker;
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
    })
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Comment: Do the markers appear if you interact with the map, especially zooming in/out? Do they appear if you remove your code for setting up custom icon/MarkerImages (thus displaying the default icons)?

Comment: Yes, the first 10 markers show up and behave normally. I will have to test using the default markers instead of the custom ones.

Comment: I suggested testing with default markers because in the past (v2?), I think there was a limit to the number distinct marker icons that could be used. Not positive though.  That test would also show whether or not your sprite handling is related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

kaliatech - you had it right. Google restricts the number of custom icons to having 10 on the map at the same time, which is pretty sweet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: although its too late but i started using the default icon, but still get 10 markers only